# How to modify code to the initComponents() method on Net Beans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, decompiling

I know this question is similar to another question in stackoverflow. But it doesnt same. 
I want to modify initcomponents method because I have old version source code of my jar file , and I have my new jar file(source code is deleted by mistakenly) I decompile my new jar and I got source but I didnot paste it on old version. Because it does not give permission. And the other problem is my .java class has form page too. And when I decompile my jar file I didnot see the myclass.form file.How can I get it back by decompile the code and how can I paste it my old source code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using NetBeans, the deleted file may yet be under local version control.

- Create a new file having the same name and location.
- Right click on the file's tab and select `History`.
- Click on the arrows to restore the missing content.
- Learn [layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and free your inner GUI designer.