# How to show GUI design view in java.class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm linking a database to `NetBeans` now and I need to create a interface for this. But when I need to adjust the position of button, label is difficult. Is it possible that show a GUI design view that easy for me to adjust without use the `JFrame` component?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, but it sounds like what you're asking for is what layout managers are supposed to do for you. Perhaps the best solution: use the best combination of layout managers. If you want a more detailed and specific answer, you may need to write a more detailed and specific question.

Comment: If you created the UI by hand, then no. You should go using trying to get things to be pixel perfect and instead focus on getting you elements aligned within there groups

Comment: As you are using Netbeans you can use gui builder mattise.. just create your `JFrame` in netbeans as a JFrame form, an enter to `Design view`

Comment: Ok I get it .. thanks!

Comment: create JFrame in netbeans and use the Design view~ ^_^

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking for a GUI builder for Swing.
Netbeans ships with the [Matisse Swing GUI Builder](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) which will help you build GUIs easily and quickly. Tutorials aren't uncommon (such as the [official tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html) or [some user created videos on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFr06ZKIpSM)).

Some folks are fine with this work flow (since it speeds up development quite a bit). Others want to use custom frameworks and have requirements to use specific layouts in which case I recommend reading about [different layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Take your pick and happy development! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to design your entire application in the GUI editor, you may be able to adapt the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513). This will let you focus on a single container at a time. Also, remember to backup your `.form` files; more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19715788/230513).