# NetBeans suddenly doesn't detect Swing components on runtime

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, build, build-error

I guess this is odd, as NetBeans GUI components are not detected by Builder, for exp "cannot find symbol variable jButton...". 
It used to work fine, but now after some minutes of latest successful build it does't work any more!

I tried to solve the problem by restarting project and  NetBeans IDE but nothing changed. How can I solve this issue?

Netbeans IDE v7.4
Mac OS 10.9.4

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: missed any import statement?

Comment: *"How can I solve this issue?"* Stop being Netbeans servant and learn how to write Java.

Comment: You mean that would be the problem with the IDE then?!

Comment: @AlanD The chances that Netbean is wrong is about zero. The chances that you are wrong are around 100%. Learn Java. And for your issue, if you want an answer, then post your code.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet YES! You were right! the problem was just an extra "}"! Thanks a lot!

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19714659/230513).